# How to get rid of "Keras weights file saving" message

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Im currently working with Keras and creating Convolutional NN. I have been always creating an architecture using Sequential() and now I tried to do it in another way [another way of creating an architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDeaJ.png). And now, whenever I execute my code it always outputs annoying message [annoying message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcbFb.png) and I dont know how to get rid of this

There is no info about such problem on the internet, but I have tried to do this

```
import os  
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

but it doesnt work

UPDATE:
I have figured out that this message appears after I do this:

```
model = Model(input_, output)
```

And now I dont know why this message appears

Comment: This annoying message is literally what your code is doing, are you aware that jupyter notebook will print result of commands if you do not assign them to a variable?

Comment: I dont know which line of code is causing this. It happened only after I changed the way of creating an architecture. According to a first screenshot everything is assigned to variables. I have just restarted my kernel and executed this block, the problem still exists

Comment: np.unique in that block of code is not assigned to any variable, so its printed to the output.

Comment: I believe that there is no correlation between np.unique and this annoying output. It happens even if I do 2+2. It started happening after I execute this block of code https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDeaJ.png

Comment: Well then provide more information, we only have the partial view, and also do not post text as images! Provide a fully working example code that reproduces the problem.